# FRAMEWORK 7 - Combining all html-sites that are located in different html-files

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, frameworks, html-framework-7

Hehoo, I'm using **[Framework 7](https://framework7.io)** to build a simple phonegap/cordova application for iOS.

Sooo. My project is separated into **different html/js-files** because otherwise it would be super confusing to find code mistakes/etc (You know what I mean :p).

All of my html-pages and js-files (even **if they are not displayed right now**) should be loaded at the same time, because they have to '*work*' in the background.

But I can not get it working to load all **html-files** into one **index.html Dom tree**.

```
mainView.router.load({url: 'page1.html'})
```

Above you can see the javascript code I'm using to **switch my pages** programatly, but *-no matter what I'm trying-* I just get two pages loaded at the same time.

Does anyone know the solution for my problem & can publish some example code **"how to load all framework7 html-sites into one dom tree"**.

I'm at my wit's end  :-(

Thanks in advance

- jojo

Answer (score 0):

practically to load all js and html files at one a time will costing performance

You should use "load on demand" method using AMD framework library like require.js

Framework 7 already give good example how to use require.js

https://github.com/philipshurpik/Framework7-Contacts7-MVC

Comment: if you try to make some background processing try to use https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp  alongside require.js